# Function returns the oldest value in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

This is a function (last) that returns the oldest value in linked list (the last node):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
  int val;
  struct node *next;
}Elem, *Pointer;

Pointer init() { return NULL; }

void last(Pointer l)
{
  while (l != NULL)
  {
    l = l->next; 
  }
  printf("%d",l->val); 
}

int main(void) {
    Pointer myl =
    insert(3, insert(7, insert(5, 
    insert(11, insert(1, init ())))));

    last(myl);
}
```

so the function (last) takes a pointer that points to a linked list, and in a while loop it moves the pointer to the last node and then prints its value.

**Error is:** `exited, segmentation fault`.

Comment: Use `while (l->next != NULL)` - first checking that `l` is not `NULL`. Note, you can also write it as `while (l->next)`

Comment: Just a note I didn't mention in my answer because I consideted it secondary: your function is void so it doesn't return the last element nor its value (it actually doesn't return anything). It just _prints_ the last value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since checking for NULL `l` is your exit condition from the loop, when you reach the end of the loop

```
while (l != NULL)
{
    l = l->next; 
}
printf("%d",l->val);
```

`l` is NULL (otherwise you would still be looping!). So in the following `printf` you are dereferencing a NULL pointer and this results in a *segmentation fault*.

You can modify your function in the following way:

```
void last(Pointer l)
{
    if ( l != NULL )
    {
        while (l->next != NULL)
        {
            l = l->next; 
        }
        printf("%d",l->val); 
    }
}
```

Just peek in the `next` field of the element, after making sure that the list is not empty (`NULL` list pointer).

Answer (score 1):

1. Never hide pointers behind the typedefs. It makes programs hard to read and error prone.

```
typedef struct node {
  int val;
  struct node *next;
}Elem;
```

2. This is something absilutelly horrible - avoid

```
insert(3, insert(7, insert(5, 
insert(11, insert(1, init ())))));
```

3. The function. Check if the next value is NULL. IMO better return pointer and then do something with it. Also Always check if parameter is valid.

```
Elem *last(Elem *first)
{
    if(first)
    {
        while(first -> next != NULL) 
        {
            first = -first -> next;
        }
    }
    return first;
}
```

4. Print it

```
printf("%d\n", last(myl) -> val);
```